# How to override VerifyEmailAddressAction in Liferay DXP

Tags: liferay, liferay-7, liferay-dxp

Is there any possibility to override or extend the core `VerifyEmailAddressAction` so that users, after clicking the token email link (with successful verification), are forced to set an initial password? There should be no initial password from the portal.

My idea is to (auto)login the user after verification and redirect to a change-password page.

But the class is not an OSGI component and it is part of portal-impl. Also, I did not find any settings or properties to configure the portal for this scenario. What could I do to modify this behavior?

Comment: Ya, it's not a easy way to solve this. It's possibile to extend the core components....but it's dangerous..

Comment: if it´s really in portal impl and no other extension point exists .. there is the "ext plugin"  but  I have to confess, that I haven't done that for dxp so far ... maybe that  ? https://portal.liferay.dev/docs/7-0/tutorials/-/knowledge_base/t/advanced-customization-with-ext-plugins